# Token error in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

Can anyone help me solve this error?

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 628,Token in error = data ]

```
private DateTime data()
{
    DateTime datasot = DateTime.Now;
    string d = datasot.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
    DateTime dd = DateTime.Parse(d);
    return dd;
}

string komanda = "UPDATE ditari SET id=@id, namazisabahut=@namazisabahut, namazidrekes=@namazidrekes," +
        "namaziakshamit=@namaziakshamit, namaziikindise=@namaziikindise, namazijacise=@namazijacise, dymbedhjeterekatesunnet=@dymbedhjeterekatesunnet," +
        "namaznate=@namaznate, leximikuranit=@leximikuranit, ndegjimidersit=@ndegjimidersit, mekatet=@mekatet," +
        "mesimilenda=@mesimilenda, mesimior=@mesimior, mesimipershkrimi=@mesimipershkrimi, akeniqenepune=@akeniqenepune," +
        "punepershkrimi=@punepershkrimi,pershkrimishkurterditor=@pershkrimishkurterditor,dhikrimengjesitdhembremjes=@dhikrimengjesitdhembremjes," +
        "estagfirullah=@estagfirullah, salavatet=@salavatet" +
        "WHERE data='"+data()+"'";

SqlCeConnection sq = new SqlCeConnection(Connection.connectionstring);
SqlCeCommand sc = new SqlCeCommand(komanda, sq);
try
{
    sq.Open();
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"id", Qasja.ID);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"namazisabahut", cbnamazisabahut.SelectedItem.ToString());
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"namazidrekes", cbnamazidrekes.SelectedItem.ToString());
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"namaziikindise", cbnamaziikindise.SelectedItem.ToString());
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"namaziakshamit", cbnamaziakshamit.SelectedItem.ToString());
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"namazijacise", cbnamazijacise.SelectedItem.ToString());

    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"dymbedhjeterekatesunnet", chkdymbedhjetrekatesunnet.CheckState);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"namaznate", chkNamazNate.CheckState);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"leximikuranit", chkLeximiKuranit.CheckState);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"ndegjimikuranit", chkLeximiKuranit.CheckState);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"ndegjimidersit", chkNdegjimiDersit.CheckState);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"mekatet", txtpershkrimimekatit.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"mesimilenda", txtmesimilenda.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"mesimior", nud_saorkenimsu.Value);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"mesimipershkrimi", txtpershkrimiMsimit.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"akeniqenepune", chkAkeniqenepune.CheckState);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"punepershkrimi", txtPershkrimiPuna.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"pershkrimishkurterditor", richtextPershkrimiDitor.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"dhikrimengjesitdhembremjes", cbdhikrimengjesitmbremjes.SelectedItem.ToString());
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"estagfirullah", chkEstigfar.CheckState);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"salavatet", chksalavatet.CheckState);
    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sc.Dispose();
    sq.Close();
```

Comment: check the string komanda produces valid sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing space before the "WHERE" in your query.

Comment: A fast way to see that is to read the error message : When you watch the value of your query, and go on line 1 (there is only 1 line) and character 628, it is just after the WHERE. So you know your problem is not far from this place.

Answer (score 1):

This is it.

```
"estagfirullah=@estagfirullah, salavatet=@salavatet" +
"WHERE data='"+data()+"'";
```

This evaluates to `estagfirullah=@estagfirullah, salavatet=@salavatetWHERE data=` which is not valid.  Put spaces in before each `"` at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed Space near the **where**

so your query look like this

[image]

so it can't be parsed.

You have to change like this

```
"UPDATE ditari SET id=@id, namazisabahut=@namazisabahut, namazidrekes=@namazidrekes," +
        "namaziakshamit=@namaziakshamit, namaziikindise=@namaziikindise, namazijacise=@namazijacise, dymbedhjeterekatesunnet=@dymbedhjeterekatesunnet," +
        "namaznate=@namaznate, leximikuranit=@leximikuranit, ndegjimidersit=@ndegjimidersit, mekatet=@mekatet," +
        "mesimilenda=@mesimilenda, mesimior=@mesimior, mesimipershkrimi=@mesimipershkrimi, akeniqenepune=@akeniqenepune," +
        "punepershkrimi=@punepershkrimi,pershkrimishkurterditor=@pershkrimishkurterditor,dhikrimengjesitdhembremjes=@dhikrimengjesitdhembremjes," +
        "estagfirullah=@estagfirullah, salavatet=@salavatet " +
        " WHERE data='"+data()+"'";
```

now it's look like this

[image]

Hope this help you